# Haskell Optimizations for List Processing stymied by Lazy Evaluation

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm trying to improve the efficiency of the following code.  I want to count all occurrences of a symbol before a given point (as part of pattern-matching using a Burrows-Wheeler transform).  There's some overlap in how I'm counting symbols.  However, when I have tried to implement what looks like it should be more efficient code, it turns out to be less efficient, and I'm assuming that lazy evaluation and my poor understanding of it is to blame.

My first attempt at a counting function went like this:

```
count :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int
count list sym pos = length . filter (== sym) . take pos $ list
```

Then in the body of the matching function itself:

```
matching str refCol pattern = match 0 (n - 1) (reverse pattern)
  where n = length str
        refFstOcc sym = length $ takeWhile (/= sym) refCol
        match top bottom [] = bottom - top + 1
        match top bottom (sym : syms) =
          let topCt = count str sym top
              bottomCt = count str sym (bottom + 1)
              middleCt = bottomCt - topCt
              refCt = refFstOcc sym
          in if middleCt > 0
               then match (refCt + topCt) (refCt + bottomCt - 1) syms
               else 0
```

(Stripped down for brevity - I'm memoizing first occurrences of symbols in refCol through a Map, and a couple other details as well).

**Edit**: Sample use would be:

```
matching "AT$TCTAGT" "$AACGTTTT" "TCG"
```

which should be 1 (assuming I didn't mistype anything).

Now, I'm recounting everything in the middle between the `top` pointer and the `bottom` twice, which adds up when I count a million character DNA string with only 4 possible choices for characters (and profiling tells me that this is the big bottleneck, too, taking 48% of my time for bottomCt and around 38% of my time for topCt).  For reference, when calculating this for a million character string and trying to match 50 patterns (each of which is between 1 and 1000 characters), the program takes about 8.5 to 9.5 seconds to run.

However, if I try to implement the following function:

```
countBetween :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
countBetween list sym top bottom =
  let (topList, bottomList) = splitAt top list
      midList = take (bottom - top) bottomList
      getSyms = length . filter (== sym)
  in (getSyms topList, getSyms midList)
```

(with changes made to the matching function to compensate), the program takes between 18 and 22 seconds to run.

I've also tried passing in a Map which can keep track of previous calls, but that also takes about 20 seconds to run and runs up the memory usage.

Similarly, I've shorted `length . filter (== sym)` to a `fold`, but again - 20 seconds for `foldr`, and 14-15 for `foldl`.

So what would be a proper Haskell way to optimize this code through rewriting it?  (Specifically, I'm looking for something that doesn't involve precomputation - I may not be reusing strings very much - and which explains something of why this is happening).

**Edit**: More clearly, what I am looking for is the following:

a) Why does this behaviour happen in Haskell?  How does lazy evaluation play a role, what optimizations is the compiler making to rewrite the `count` and `countBetween` functions, and what other factors may be involved?

b) What is a simple code rewrite which would address this issue so that I don't traverse the lists multiple times?  I'm looking specifically for something which addresses that issue, rather than a solution which sidesteps it.  If the final answer is, `count` is the most efficient possible way to write the code, why is that?

Comment: Can you give a sample input (even if drastically reduced)?

Comment: `length . filter` can be trivially shortened to a fold.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `str` parameter to `matching`? It seems that `n` should equal `length refCol` or something like that.

Comment: @pdexter: sample input added.

Comment: @ErikR: There's the str which was passed in, which is transformed under the BW transform, and a reference column, which is the sorted version.  `zip str refCol` gives the two-character strings in the original input, and this algorithm keeps going back and forth between them in matching a pattern (potentially one with mutations).

Comment: @ThreeFx: Thanks!  That was my next question, whether `length . filter ...` automatically folded things down upon execution, or whether it would traverse the list twice.

Comment: I ask because except for `n = length str` the parameter `str` is never referenced in `matching`. So it seems we could also define `n = length refCol`, right?

Comment: It shouldn't traverse twice with optimizations. However running your sample returns 0 for me.

Comment: @ErikR , @pdexter: Oops, meant to call count using `str` instead of `refCol`.  Only `refFirstOcc` should use `refCol`.  That should fix both.

Comment: Tried the `fold` method too.  Same problem - jumps to 20 seconds.

Comment: You are compiling with optimizations, right?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, `ghc -O` (`-rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto`) to compile

Comment: So it seems that `refCol` is just a sorted version of `str`, right?

Comment: @ErikR: Yes.  It's part of the calculation too, but that I seem to have relatively efficient.

Comment: If you compute the counts of each letter you'll know the structure of the refCol string and you won't need to actually construct it. See the `matching`' function in  http://lpaste.net/174292#line128  for a version which only uses `str`.

Comment: @ErikR: Yeah, that's pretty much how I have it right now.

Comment: @nomicflux That's no way to compile if you're looking at performance numbers.  `-O2` gets you good benefits much of the time with tight code.  And `-prof` destroys most optimizations.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, but I'm trying to figure out what to change to get better numbers, and `prof` is how I'm doing that.  And while I do plan on using `O2`, I'm also trying to understand the algorithmic issues here rather than just shunting it all off to the compiler.

Comment: @nomicflux But prof reports are misleading - it doesn't give you a very useful picture, or even gives you a down right misleading picture, as to the costs.  These costs can be vastly different after inlining, deforestation and all the other optimizations which are often prevented in order to preserve the cost centers needed by prof.  More-over, the actual run time changes drastically and in inconsistent ways so you can not believably argue one algorithm is faster than another.

Comment: @Thomas: "you can not believably argue one algorithm is faster than another".  I suspect that the entire field of algorithmic analysis would disagree.  But regardless, in this question, I am looking for *why* doing the repeated work costs less time than trying to do the work more efficiently, and (since the one algorithm is clearly and regularly slower than the other, `-prof` or not, `-O` or `-O2`) what I could do to code it more efficiently.  That is the point of the question.  I want understanding; the immediate performance of this chunk of code by any means possible is less important.

Comment: @Thomas (cont) Also, thanks to @ErikR 's efforts below, I was able to get this down to under a second for a million character string, using 5000 patterns of size up to 1000 (and that's under a second even using `-O -prof`.  So there **are** algorithmic strategies for dealing with this.  I'm still looking for an answer as to what exactly is going on in the code to make it this wonky, but there are more things to try (and things far more helpful) than a new compiler flag.

Comment: @nomicflux I don't get it.  Are you chewing me out for related comments?  I usually try to communicate two facts on performance threads, facts that matter tremendously in some cases (and not in others).  The one you seem to dislike is that using prof can change performance including the actual complexity of the resulting code (depending on GC specifics).  I'm glad you found suitable answers, hopefully you'll accept them.

Comment: @Thomas: In my first comment, I was willing to simply say, "I'm trying to understand the algorithmic issues here."  The point was not, how do I get this faster (using C would also work, but is not relevant), it was, what's going on code-wise which makes this slow?  So I understand the misunderstanding, it just wasn't what I was looking for.  Thanks for your time.  
But you then went on to ignore that, and moreover argue with me that I can't actually do algorithmic analysis here.  So forgive the forthrightness, but I didn't feel like I was getting my point across in a subtler fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure lazy evaluation has much to do with the performance of the code. I think the main problem is the use of String - which is a linked list - instead of more performant string type.

Note that this call in your `countBetween` function:

```
  let (topList, bottomList) = splitAt top list
```

will re-create the linked link corresponding to `topList` meaning
a lot more allocations.

A Criterion benchmark to compare `splitAt` versus using `take n/drop n`
may be found here: http://lpaste.net/174526. The `splitAt` version is
about 3 times slower and, of course, has a lot more allocations.

Even if you don't want to "pre-compute" the counts you can improve
matters a great deal by simply switching to either ByteString or Text.

Define:

```
countSyms :: Char -> ByteString -> Int -> Int -> Int
countSyms sym str lo hi =
  length [ i | i <- [lo..hi], BS.index str i == sym ]
```

and then:

```
countBetween :: ByteString -> Char -> Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)
countBetween str sym top bottom = (a,b)
  where a = countSyms sym str 0 (top-1)
        b = countSyms sym str top (bottom-1)
```

Also, don't use `reverse` on large lists - it will reallocate the
entire list. Just index into a ByteString / Text in reverse.

Memoizing counts may or may not help. It all depends on how it's done.

Comment: Perfect - that was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the main point of the `match` routine is
to transform a interval `(bottom,top)` to another interval
based on the current symbol `sym`. The formulas are
basically:

```
ref_fst = index of sym in ref_col
  -- defined in an outer scope

match :: Char -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)
match sym (bottom, top) | bottom > top =  (bottom, top) -- if the empty interval
match sym (bottom, top) =
  let 
    top_count = count of sym in str from index 0 to top
    bot_count = count of sym in str from index 0 to bottom
    mid_count = top_count - bot_count
  in if mid_count > 0
         then (ref_fst + bot_count, ref_fst + top_count)
         else (1,0)  -- the empty interval
```

And then `matching` is just a fold over `pattern` using `match`
with the initial interval `(0, n-1)`.

Both `top_count` and `bot_count` can be computed efficiently
using a precomputed lookup table, and below is code which
does that.

If you run `test1` you'll see a trace of how the interval
is transformed via each symbol in the pattern.

Note: There may be off-by-1 errors, and I've hard coded
`ref_fst` to be 0 - I'm not sure how this fits into the
larger algorithm, but the basic idea should be sound.

Note that once the `counts` vector has been created
there is no need to index into the original string anymore.
Therefore, even though I use a ByteString here for
the (larger) DNA sequence, it's not crucial, and the
`mkCounts` routine should work just as well if passed a String
instead.

Code also available at http://lpaste.net/174288

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Vector.Unboxed ((!))
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UVM
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Debug.Trace
import Text.Printf
import Data.List

mkCounts :: BS.ByteString -> UV.Vector (Int,Int,Int,Int)
mkCounts syms = UV.create $ do
  let n = BS.length syms
  v <- UVM.new (n+1)
  let loop x i | i >= n = return x
      loop x i = let s = BS.index syms i
                     (a,t,c,g) = x
                     x' = case s of
                            'A' -> (a+1,t,c,g)
                            'T' -> (a,t+1,c,g)
                            'C' -> (a,t,c+1,g)
                            'G' -> (a,t,c,g+1)
                            _   -> x
                 in do UVM.write v i x
                       loop x' (i+1) 
  x <- loop (0,0,0,0) 0
  UVM.write v n x
  return v

data DNA = A | C | T | G
  deriving (Show)

getter :: DNA -> (Int,Int,Int,Int) -> Int
getter A (a,_,_,_) = a
getter T (_,t,_,_) = t
getter C (_,_,c,_) = c
getter G (_,_,_,g) = g

-- narrow a window
narrow :: Int -> UV.Vector (Int,Int,Int,Int) -> DNA -> (Int,Int) ->  (Int,Int)

narrow refcol counts sym (lo,hi) | trace msg False = undefined
  where msg = printf "-- lo: %d  hi: %d  refcol: %d  sym: %s  top_cnt: %d  bot_count: %d" lo hi refcol (show sym) top_count bot_count
        top_count = getter sym (counts ! (hi+1))
        bot_count = getter sym (counts ! lo)

narrow refcol counts sym (lo,hi) =
  let top_count = getter sym (counts ! (hi+1))
      bot_count = getter sym (counts ! (lo+0))
      mid_count = top_count - bot_count
  in if mid_count > 0
       then ( refcol + bot_count, refcol + top_count-1 )
       else (lo+1,lo)  -- signal an wmpty window

findFirst :: DNA -> UV.Vector (Int,Int,Int,Int)  -> Int
findFirst sym v =
  let n = UV.length v
      loop i | i >= n = n
      loop i = if getter sym (v ! i) > 0
                 then i
                 else loop (i+1)
  in loop 0

toDNA :: String -> [DNA]
toDNA str = map charToDNA str

charToDNA :: Char -> DNA
charToDNA = go
  where go 'A' = A
        go 'C' = C
        go 'T' = T
        go 'G' = G

dnaToChar A = 'A'
dnaToChar C = 'C'
dnaToChar T = 'T'
dnaToChar G = 'G'

first :: DNA -> BS.ByteString -> Int
first sym str = maybe len id (BS.elemIndex (dnaToChar sym) str)
  where len = BS.length str

test2 = do
 -- matching "AT$TCTAGT" "$AACGTTTT" "TCG"
  let str    = "AT$TCTAGT"
      refcol = "$AACGTTTT"
      syms   = toDNA "TCG"

      -- hard coded for now
      -- may be computeed an memoized
      refcol_G = 4
      refcol_C = 3
      refcol_T = 5

      counts = mkCounts str
      w0 = (0, BS.length str -1)

      w1 = narrow refcol_G counts G w0
      w2 = narrow refcol_C counts C w1
      w3 = narrow refcol_T counts T w2

      firsts = (first A refcol, first T refcol, first C refcol, first G refcol)

  putStrLn $ "firsts: " ++ show firsts

  putStrLn $ "w0: " ++ show w0
  putStrLn $ "w1: " ++ show w1
  putStrLn $ "w2: " ++ show w2
  putStrLn $ "w3: " ++ show w3
  let (lo,hi) = w3
      len = if lo <= hi then hi - lo + 1 else 0
  putStrLn $ "length: " ++ show len

matching :: BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString -> String -> Int
matching  str refcol pattern = 
  let counts = mkCounts str
      n = BS.length str
      syms = toDNA (reverse pattern)
      firsts = (first A refcol, first T refcol, first C refcol, first G refcol)

      go (lo,hi) sym = narrow refcol counts sym (lo,hi)
        where refcol = getter sym firsts

      (lo, hi) = foldl' go (0,n-1) syms
      len = if lo <= hi then hi - lo + 1 else 0
  in len

test3 = matching "AT$TCTAGT" "$AACGTTTT" "TCG"
```

Comment: Code updated - I'm pretty sure it is compatible with your algorithm. Try `test2` and `test3`. Also available at http://lpaste.net/174288

Comment: Taking back my previous comment - evidently there was something wrong in my Array implementation.  Using an Array and `unfoldr` in a similar fashion to the above solves the time problem nicely.  Though now I have a memory problem, so still trying to figure out how to do this in place....

Comment: A lot depends on how you construct the Array. The Vector code above can compute the counts for an input of length 1 million in about 1/10 of a second.

Comment: Looking through this, is there a particular benefit to putting `narrow` as its own function separate from the recursion and putting it into a `foldl'`?  Or is that more of a stylistic choice?

Comment: It makes it easier to test - it is, after all, the crucial piece of logic in that loop. It also makes it more obvious that we are computing successive intervals.

Comment: btw - if you make `narrow` return a Maybe you can use `foldM` to stop iterating once the empty interval (i.e. Nothing) has been returned by narrow. See a simplified example here: http://lpaste.net/174534

Comment: Great. That's helpful.  I think I'm going to take some time to study what you did with this code - thanks.